# `set timezone to 'EEST'` in postgres gives me error. Why?

Tags: postgresql, timezone

In postgres I can setup and read timezone:

```
dev=> set timezone to 'UTC';
SET
dev=> select current_setting( 'timezone' );
 current_setting 
-----------------
 UTC
(1 row)
```

There is `EEST` timezone:

```
select exists( select 1 from pg_timezone_names where abbrev = 'EEST' );
 exists 
--------
 t
(1 row)
```

Why I can not setup it?

```
dev=> set timezone to 'EEST';
ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "EEST"
```

Comment: It seems that you can't set the summer time specifically in Postgres. However, you can do `set timezone to 'EET'` which should be the same time zone.

Comment: @Cornholio: It is not same. Its `utc_offset` is `02:00:00` instead of `03:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `<xocolatl>`.

The error is because in the `pg_timezone_names` there is no timezone with `EEST` name, but there is timezone with `UTC` name:

```
select * from pg_timezone_names where name = 'UTC';
 name | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst 
------+--------+------------+--------
 UTC  | UTC    | 00:00:00   | f
(1 row)
```